# How can I optimize the combination that contains repeated values?

Tags: javascript, recursion, optimization, combinations, repeat

I have an array with three values.

```
["a","b","c"]
```

I'm trying to create the following combination with the above array.

```
0:  ["a", "a", "a"]
1:  ["a", "a", "b"]
2:  ["a", "a", "c"]
3:  ["a", "b", "b"]
4:  ["a", "b", "c"]
5:  ["a", "c", "c"]
6:  ["b", "b", "b"]
7:  ["b", "b", "c"]
8:  ["b", "c", "c"]
9:  ["c", "c", "c"]
```

I wrote the code that was successful. But the code is not optimized. How can I make this code simple.

```
function test(arr, arr2=[], result=[]) {
    if (arr2.length < 3) {
        let proxy_arr = [...arr];
        Object.keys(proxy_arr).forEach(index=>{
            if (!test(arr, [...arr2].concat(proxy_arr[index]), result)) {
                result.push([...arr2].concat(proxy_arr[index]));

            } else {
                //debugger;
                arr = arr.slice(1);
            }

        }
        );
        return result;

    }
    return false;
}
result = test(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

Comment: To make it clear, would you like to create a more efficient method to find all the possible permutation including the numbers in your array?

Comment: I would google for "Brute force JavaScript" and read into some examples, because your use-case is essentially that of Brute force.

Comment: @Christheoreo I don't want to use the permutation. Values can be repeated. however, the generated arrays cannot be repeated. eg:["a","a","b"],["b","a","a"]. I don't want like this.

Comment: Hi check my answer for your query

Comment: Maybe I can create a nested function. I move the "return result" code to the external function and the function can be set to one parameter. It flexes the code a bit.

Comment: @EfeZeybek please see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563754/633183)

Comment: @user633183: That answer is -- as always -- excellent.  But unless my quick read missed it, it does not answer this problem, which is, I guess, to find the number of mutisets/bags of size `n` with elements drawn from a given set.  (Of course it's not until after I write my own answer that I recognize this formulation!)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Nice answer. I did see that the problem is slightly different but I figured the simple algorithms would show the OP how to reason about the problem and discover a solution on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function to do most of the work.  `Array.from` a generator will stuff the results in an array.

```js
let vec = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function* combo(n, k = 0, prefix = []) {
  if (n == 0) yield prefix;
  else for (let i = k; i < vec.length; ++i) {
    yield* combo(n - 1, i, [...prefix, vec[i]]);
  }
}

let test = Array.from(combo(3));

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Comment: clean solution but verbiage like _"that's super easy..."_ can rub people the wrong way

Comment: @user633183, agreed.  Thanks.  I will adjust the tone.

Comment: This is much cleaner than my solution.  Cleaner still would be passing `vec` as a parameter, removing `k` (starting the loop at `i = 0`), and using `vec.slice(i)` on the recursive call.

Comment: Would it be better to use this code`Math.max(0,vec.indexOf(prefix[0]))` instead of k to make it better? and we need to edit that code.`yield* combo(n - 1, [vec[i],...prefix]);`

Comment: @EfeZeybek feel free to propose your own answer.  I stand by my implementation, because `indexOf` has a less efficient linear cost as opposed to a constant cost the way I've implemented it.

Comment: I asked if the code could be a little better. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated Version

Inspired by [Wyck's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57187169), I made another version.  This one is much cleaner.  It uses much the same technique as Wyck did, but skips the generator code.

```js
const makeBags = (n, xs, prefix = []) => 
  n == 0
    ? [prefix]
    : xs .flatMap ((v, i) => makeBags (n - 1, xs .slice (i), [...prefix, v]))

console .log (
  JSON .stringify (makeBags (3, ['a', 'b', 'c']))
)
```

Note that although the additional default parameter looks like it might be for tail-call optimization, this code is *not* ready for TCO.

### My First Solution

Here is a straightforward recursive solution, returning the empty list if the list of letters is empty and otherwise determining how many of the initial letter to include and recurring on the remaining letters.  I have no idea if this is more optimal in any sense than the original except in terms of code cleanliness.  But it's more generic, accepting an argument to tell how many items are in the output separate from the number of items in the list.

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  [...Array (hi + 1 - lo)] .map ((_, i) => i + lo)

const prefixAll = (p, xs) => 
  xs .map (x => [...p, ...x])

const groupsOf = (n, [x = undefined, ...xs]) =>  
  x == undefined
    ? []
    : [
        Array (n) .fill (x), 
        ...range (1, n) .flatMap (i => prefixAll (Array (n - i) .fill (x), groupsOf (i, xs)))
      ]

console .log (
  groupsOf (3, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
)
```

`range` is a simple utility function: `range(3, 10) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

`prefixAll` is a helper, which could be inlined if preferred.  It simply prefixes each array in the second argument with the values in the first one.

```
prefixAll(['a', 'b'], [['c'], ['c', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]) 
//=> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

While this isn't overly complex, there is almost certainly a better solution which does not involve `Array (n) .fill (x)`, doing the recursive step as one simple `flatMap`.  But I don't have time now to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

you are taking about the permutation algorithm.

here is solution without repitation

```js
function permutateWithoutRep(permutationOptions) {
  if (permutationOptions.length === 1) {
    return [permutationOptions];
  }

  // Init permutations array.
  const permutations = [];

  // Get all permutations for permutationOptions excluding the first element.
  const smallerPermutations = permutateWithoutRep(permutationOptions.slice(1));

  // Insert first option into every possible position of every smaller permutation.
  const firstOption = permutationOptions[0];

  for (let permIndex = 0; permIndex < smallerPermutations.length; permIndex += 1) {
    const smallerPermutation = smallerPermutations[permIndex];

    // Insert first option into every possible position of smallerPermutation.
    for (let positionIndex = 0; positionIndex <= smallerPermutation.length; positionIndex += 1) {
      const permutationPrefix = smallerPermutation.slice(0, positionIndex);
      const permutationSuffix = smallerPermutation.slice(positionIndex);
      permutations.push(permutationPrefix.concat([firstOption], permutationSuffix));
    }
  }

  return permutations;
}

console.log(permutateWithoutRep(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

With Repitation:

```js
function permutateWithRep(
  permutationOptions,
  permutationLength = permutationOptions.length,
) {
  if (permutationLength === 1) {
    return permutationOptions.map(permutationOption => [permutationOption]);
  }

  // Init permutations array.
  const permutations = [];

  // Get smaller permutations.
  const smallerPermutations = permutateWithRep(
    permutationOptions,
    permutationLength - 1,
  );

  // Go through all options and join it to the smaller permutations.
  permutationOptions.forEach((currentOption) => {
    smallerPermutations.forEach((smallerPermutation) => {
      permutations.push([currentOption].concat(smallerPermutation));
    });
  });

  return permutations;
}

console.log(permutateWithRep(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Comment: Note that neither of these answers the question.  Just compare the requested output with either of them.

Comment: You can see that there is a combination by looking at the total numbers "a", "b", "c" in each array.

Comment: @Rishab, your answer includes the undesired result: `["a", "b", "a"]`  You have given all permutations.  That's not what was asked for.  You would need to filter out permutations where items occur out of order from the order they occurred in the original array.  Order should be preserved.  (For example, the original list was in alphabetical order, but you have produced some combos that are not in alphabetical order.)

Comment: @Wyck: I don't know the OP's requirements.  Although your solution and mine do preserve order, I don't know if, say, any of `['a', 'a', 'b']`, `['a', 'b', 'a']`, or `['b', 'a', 'a']` would be acceptable, so long as one of them is there.  I'm really thinking of the results as a multiset expressed as an array, and not a vector expressed as one.